# Worst margin when halving a hypercube with a hyperplane

Tags: discrete-geometry, machine-learning

Consider the $n$-cube $C_n=\lbrace-1,1\rbrace^n$ and the problem of partitioning it into halves with hyperplanes through the origin that avoid all its points. We can parameterize the hyperplanes by their unit normals, $u\in S_n$, and for each partition we can optimize $u$ to increase the "margin", the minimum distance between the hyperplane and the points of $C_n$. What is the worst optimized margin (distance) $d_n$ when we consider all possible partitions?

The *number* of partitions for $n=1,2,3,4\ldots$ is the sequence $2,4,14,104,\ldots$ (OEIS entry A000609). The corresponding worst margins are $d_n=1,1,1/\sqrt{3},\ldots$ . What is known about the latter sequence? Do the terms have a simple (nontrivial) lower bound?

Here's an equivalent definition of the numbers $d_n$. Let $M_n$ be the set of nonsingular $n\times n$ matrices with $\pm 1$ elements. The rows of a matrix $m\in M_n$ are $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and there is a unique hyperplane that passes through all of them. The distance to this hyperplane is
$$\mathrm{dist}(m)=\frac{1}{\|m^{-1} e\|},$$
where $e$ is the vector of all 1's. The numbers $d_n$ are the minimum of $\mathrm{dist}(m)$ over all $m\in M_n$.

Here is what I know about these numbers:

$n\qquad d_n$

$1\qquad 1$

$2\qquad 1$

$3\qquad 1/\sqrt{3}$

$4\qquad 1/\sqrt{7}$

$5\qquad 1/\sqrt{19}$

The function $\mathrm{dist}(m)$ is also defined when $m$ has fewer than $n$ rows: the distance to the affine closure of the $n$ or fewer points of the hypercube. It seems reasonable that the minimum of $\mathrm{dist}(m)$ is only realized with no less than $n$ linearly independent points, but what's the proof?